# Custom class loader wtih Infinispan 9.4.x

Tags: infinispan-9, wildfly-17

We have been using old version of infinispan and wildfly ( 10.x and infinispan 6.x ). The cache has been used as embedded cache, e.g it was started from the application code ( which was actually the wildfly module ).Whenever cache was created in clustered mode the code created a Decorated Cache with specific class loader which allowed to handle remote data transfer and provided all the required classes.
In inifinspan 9.4.x the with(ClassLoader) is deprecated on both AdvancedCache and DecoratedCache and while checking the code we have found that it does nothing.
As result when the cache item is stored and sent to remote node remote exception is occuring (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

```
15:32:45,028 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (jgroups-10,ip-10-0-0-82-23088) ISPN000136: Error executing command PrepareCommand on Cache 'ra-data-SipRA'
```

, writing keys [1-14341@127.0.0.1:c803fe42:null]: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from ip-10-0-0-82-50680, see cause for remote stack trace
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:28)

```
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:123)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:104)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1079)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1355)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:205)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalJBossMarshaller.objectFromObjectStream(ExternalJBossMarshaller.java:47)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readUnknown(GlobalMarshaller.java:873)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:697)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:361)
```

Source code shows that global configuration is storing class loader now and it is provided from wildfly. Is there any way to provide the custom class loader for infinispan 9.x or at least define which one to use on remote operation handling

BR
Yulian Oifa